# SQL Query extract data from a value

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery

One of my columns has a web address in it (e.g. [http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/512t20phTmL.*SL1200*.jpg](http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/512t20phTmL._SL1200_.jpg))

How can I get it to extract just the file name?

I am using the current query:

```
SELECT
  PRODUCT.PRODUCTID,
  PRODUCT.CATEGORYID,
  PRODUCT.PRODUCTNAME,
  PRODUCT.PRODUCTDESCRIPTION,
  PRODUCT.UNITPRICE,
  PRODUCT.PICTURE
FROM
  PRODUCT
```

Real basic, I know, but I'm new :)

What would I add to only show the filename from PRODUCT.PICTURE?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Not sure you can do this in SQL, but you can technically write a PHP script that does the query, loops through the results and then parses out the filename for you.

Comment: Do you realize that you gave a link to an image of a digital thermostat?  Maybe this question belongs on the home improvement site.

Comment: I know it must be possible as I have to do it as part of a single-row functions demo, and I am stuck. As far as the pic, it's just an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Oracle, [REGEXP_SUBSTR](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/functions116.htm) should do it in a fairly straight forward way;

```
SELECT
  PRODUCT.PRODUCTID,
  PRODUCT.CATEGORYID,
  PRODUCT.PRODUCTNAME,
  PRODUCT.PRODUCTDESCRIPTION,
  PRODUCT.UNITPRICE,
  PRODUCT.PICTURE,
  REGEXP_SUBSTR(PRODUCT.PICTURE, '[^/]*$') AS FILENAME
FROM
  PRODUCT
```

Comment: Outstanding! Thanks for the fast response! I can finally go to bed.